# How to push files from a git bare repo AFTER commit with post-receive

Tags: git

I created a tracking repo on a windows server with a post-receive hook. When I commit and push to the tracking repo, the post-receive hook will then deploy all of the files to a certain location. I noticed that my post-receive did not have a remove all files so there are some old files left behind. I deleted all of the files in that network location.

Since I've already committed, how do I rerun the deployment of the files? Can I do it from another git hook? In the file location, I suppose I could do a git clone and then a pull manually but is there way to do it from a hook?

Comment: How do you deploy from the hook? Can you repeat the deployment process manually?

Comment: I do a git commit.

Comment: After a commit you do a push and there is a deploy process in the `post-receive` hook at the server. What is that deploy process and could you repeat it manually at the server?

Comment: It looks like this --- if [[ $ref = refs/heads/master ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=$TRAGET  --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f master

Comment: Run `git --work-tree=$TRAGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f master` from the command line at the server (well, use the proper paths, of course).

Comment: Tried and getting this - Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production...
fatal: Unable to create 'file\index.lock': File exists.

Comment: [`rm $GIT_DIR/index.lock`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Unable+to+create+index.lock+File+exists)

Comment: Ok did that, now get - Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production...
Unlink of file '.editorconfig' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)

Comment: Do you run these commands as the user that normally runs the `post-receive` hook?

Comment: No on the rm $GIT and .editorconfig.